Replicated & Distributed Clickhouse - Keeper Replication
I need to create the replication in clickhouse; on two different machines that are under the same network. I have tried to configure it but I have the following error:
SQL Error [999] [07000]: Code: 999. Coordination::Exception: All connection tries failed while connecting to ZooKeeper. do not give
Server 1: 192.168.101.105 docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  clickhouse_demo:
    image: yandex/clickhouse-server:latest
    container_name: clickhouse-demo
    hostname: clickhouse-demo
    environment:
      - CLICKHOUSE_CONFIG=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
      - CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD=tecate.01
    volumes:
      - ./clickhouse_demo/config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
      - - ./clickhouse_node/data:/var/lib/clickhouse'
    mem_limit: 32g
    cpus: "6"
    ports:
      - "8123:8123"
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - clickhouse-keeper-demo
  clickhouse-keeper-demo:
    image: clickhouse/clickhouse-keeper:latest
    container_name: clickhouse-keeper-demo
    hostname: clickhouse-keeper-demo
    volumes:
     - ./clickhouse_keeper_demo/clickhouse-keeper/keeper_config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-keeper/keeper_config.xml
    ports:
        - "9181:9181"

config.xml
<remote_servers>
        <my_cluster>
            <shard>
                <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <host>192.168.101.105</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <user>default</user>
                    <password>tecate.01</password>
                </replica>
            </shard>
            <shard>
                <replica>
                    <host>192.168.101.104</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <user>default</user>
                    <password>tecate.01</password>
                </replica>
            </shard>
        </my_cluster>
    
    <zookeeper>
        <node>
            <host>192.168.101.105</host>
            <port>9181</port>
        </node>
        <node>
            <host>192.168.101.105</host>
            <port>9181</port>
        </node>
    </zookeeper>
<macros>
        <shard>01</shard>
        <replica>01</replica>
        <cluster>my_cluster</cluster>
    </macros>

keeper.xml
<clickhouse replace="true">
    <logger>
        <level>information</level>
        <log>/var/log/clickhouse-keeper/clickhouse-keeper.log</log>
        <errorlog>/var/log/clickhouse-keeper/clickhouse-keeper.err.log</errorlog>
        <size>1000M</size>
        <count>3</count>
    </logger>
    <listen_host>0.0.0.0</listen_host>
    <keeper_server>
        <tcp_port>9181</tcp_port>
        <server_id>1</server_id>
        <log_storage_path>/var/lib/clickhouse/coordination/log</log_storage_path>
        <snapshot_storage_path>/var/lib/clickhouse/coordination/snapshots</snapshot_storage_path>
        <coordination_settings>
            <operation_timeout_ms>10000</operation_timeout_ms>
            <session_timeout_ms>30000</session_timeout_ms>
            <raft_logs_level>information</raft_logs_level>
        </coordination_settings>
        <raft_configuration>
            <server>
                <id>1</id>
                <hostname>192.168.101.105</hostname>
                <port>8444</port>
            </server>
            <server>
                <id>2</id>
                <hostname>192.168.101.104</hostname>
                <port>8444</port>
            </server>
        </raft_configuration>
    </keeper_server>
</clickhouse>

Server 2: 192.168.101.104 docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  clickhouse_node:
    image: yandex/clickhouse-server:latest
    container_name: clickhouse-node
    hostname: clickhouse-node
    environment:
      - CLICKHOUSE_CONFIG=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
      - CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD=tecate.01
    volumes:
      - ./clickhouse_node/config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
      - ./clickhouse_node/data:/var/lib/clickhouse
    mem_limit: 32g
    cpus: "6"
    ports:
      - "8123:8123"
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - clickhouse-keeper-node
  clickhouse-keeper-node:
    image: clickhouse/clickhouse-keeper:latest
    container_name: clickhouse-keeper-node
    hostname: clickhouse-keeper-node
    volumes:
     - ./clickhouse_keeper_node/clickhouse-keeper/keeper_config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-keeper/keeper_config.xml
    ports:
        - "9181:9181"

config.xml
<remote_servers>
        <my_cluster>
            <shard>
                <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <host>192.168.101.105</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <user>default</user>
                    <password>tecate.01</password>
                </replica>
            </shard>
            <shard>
                <replica>
                    <host>192.168.101.104</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                    <user>default</user>
                    <password>tecate.01</password>
                </replica>
            </shard>
        </my_cluster>
    
    <zookeeper>
        <node>
            <host>192.168.101.105</host>
            <port>9181</port>
        </node>
        <node>
            <host>192.168.101.105</host>
            <port>9181</port>
        </node>
    </zookeeper>
<macros>
        <shard>01</shard>
        <replica>02</replica>
        <cluster>my_cluster</cluster>
    </macros>

keeper.xml
<clickhouse replace="true">
    <logger>
        <level>information</level>
        <log>/var/log/clickhouse-keeper/clickhouse-keeper.log</log>
        <errorlog>/var/log/clickhouse-keeper/clickhouse-keeper.err.log</errorlog>
        <size>1000M</size>
        <count>3</count>
    </logger>
    <listen_host>0.0.0.0</listen_host>
    <keeper_server>
        <tcp_port>9181</tcp_port>
        <server_id>2</server_id>
        <log_storage_path>/var/lib/clickhouse/coordination/log</log_storage_path>
        <snapshot_storage_path>/var/lib/clickhouse/coordination/snapshots</snapshot_storage_path>
        <coordination_settings>
            <operation_timeout_ms>10000</operation_timeout_ms>
            <session_timeout_ms>30000</session_timeout_ms>
            <raft_logs_level>information</raft_logs_level>
        </coordination_settings>
        <raft_configuration>
            <server>
                <id>1</id>
                <hostname>192.168.101.105</hostname>
                <port>8444</port>
            </server>
            <server>
                <id>2</id>
                <hostname>192.168.101.104</hostname>
                <port>8444</port>
            </server>
        </raft_configuration>
    </keeper_server>
</clickhouse>

I want the two clickhouse instances to be able to communicate with each other. Thank you very much!

Have you tried changing the ports of 9181:9181?

I have already tried with port 2181 and 9181, the error is still the same

Try with 9182:9182

You missed to add port 8444:8444 to your docker-compose.yaml for clickhouse-keeper-demo
your keeper instances described in raft_configuration can't achieve quorum
but better use only 1 or 3 clickhouse-keeper instances (1 for your) to avoid split-brain situation
